# How can I get the exact URL when receive emails from Kentico CMS?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am not getting the desired URL which I've entered in the email widget created in Kentico CMS. I've created a widget containing title, description and anchor url field.

When i use that widget and enter the values in the fields and send the email.
But when I get email in the browser, gets title and description as I entered. but don't getting the desired url.

I entered URL value "https://www.google.com/" but when I click that link in the email gets this URL

> "myDomain/CMSModules/Newsletters/CMSPages/Redirect.ashx?linkguid=abc16017-65f7-4da9-a71b-b1aeb5922a06&email=umair%40kco.ie&hash=059b41160c72608ec8fc8e5d71fde27143eff5c7a7f9b43f163a8d36ae5dabbf"

Please address

```
<td>{% Header_Circulation_Title %}</td>

<td>{% Header_Circulation_Description %}</td>

<td>{% Header_Circulation_Link %}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of link tracking. The url you posted will simply track the e-mail & contact of user who clicked on the link and then it will redirect you to original link source - google.com.

If you disable link tracking, this **redirect** handler should not be used.

Comment: It's not redirecting to required URL,

Comment: So, for the desired thing I must need to disable link tracking?